# Strategy to handle race conditions with regrads to web applicaiton backend?

Tags: multithreading, web-applications, backend, race-condition

I have been asked questions regarding race conditions in web application like movie ticket or travel website often in interviews.

Question is something like this.

> Say for a bus or plane ticket website, there is only seat left. Two(or many in extreme scenario) users on different computer log into the website at the same time and see that one seat is left. They both go ahead, select that seat and place the order.

Now there are two requests we have to handle. For the first request, we will book the ticket and but for the second request, we have to sort-of throw an error and show the error message to the end user saying the seat is not available. 
Say the database schema is some-thing like this:

> bus_id, seat_id,is_taken

so for the first request, we make the is_taken for corresponding bus_id, seat_id 1. Then for the second request, there won't be any seat_id with is_taken =0 so we won't book the ticket.

But here, in my opinion, we have put a restriction that at one time, only one request can be handled; Second request can be handled, only after first request has been completed.

However that is not practical, since we might have a huge website with loads of traffic and application running on several servers in parallel. We have to process requests in parallel.

Since I don't have much experience with handling race conditions in these sorts of multi-threaded web applications, I can't quite figure, what is the right way about solving this.

What is the right(even if basic) approach/ design patterns to tackle these scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point, there has to be some sort of synchronization.
Since you're using a database, which is usually the bottleneck anyway, you might as well let it handle the race condition.

All you have to do is update the row atomically. The requests can still be handled in parallel by the application.

Sql-pseudocode:

```
DECLARE @success = false;

UPDATE bus_seats
SET is_taken = 1, success = true
WHERE seat_id = @seat_id AND is_taken=0

return @success;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please explain what you mean by 'update the row atomically'?

Comment: @Dude Basically, update the row in a thread-safe way. My pseudocode show one way to 1) checker whether the seat is taken 2) take it *if* it hasn't been taken already and 3) return whether the operation was successful. Another way of ensuring the operation is atomic is using locks, like Abhijith suggests, but I think you can get away without having to use locks.

Answer (score 2):

Web applictions are necessarily multithreaded. There are two ways of solving this.

1. Application level (Not preferred)
   I am not sure which programming language are you using for building the application. But all the programming language used for building websites will have something like "synchornize" which allows you to prevent two threads accessing same block of code simultaneously.
   This is not preferred as this solution is not horizontally scalable. When you decide to do the increase the capacity by running one more instance of your web application, this solution fails terribly.
2. Database level
   This is the preferred solution. You obtain the lock on the record in the database before you update. 
   SQL provides an option for selecting the record for update.

   `SELECT * FROM BUS_SEATS WHERE BUS_ID = 1 FOR UPDATE;`

   Above sql is one way to obtain lock. All the database provide this kind of feature. With this feature you can lock the required row and do the update and ensure consistency in the database.